# Can I add a user to a single repository of an organization?

Tags: github

I can add users to a Github organization so that they can work an all repositories. But how can I add users to a single repository of that organization? Just like it is easily done for repositories attached to a single person but not organization.

Comment: Perhaps create a team, add a person to it, and give access to the repository to that team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I had to create a team and assign both the user and the repository. There is a [Github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-team) about how to create new teams.